# Send a request with automatic encoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, encode

I'm sending a request like that :

```
self.message =[self.message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"§§§"];
    self.message =[self.message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"--$--"];
    self.message =[self.message stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"-<#-"];

    NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"id_user=%@&message=%@&mode=%@&list_id=%@&date_expired=%@&enterprise_id=%@",
                                                id_user,self.message,etc.. objectForKey:@"id_enterprise"]];


    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

   // etc
```

So, why i'm using stringByReplace ? Because if the message contains " ' " or " & ", it can cause some problems to the url like id_user = ijdij&toi &message = ..
That's say, there will be conflict with & for exemple.

So I wonder if there are some method or something else than can be resolve this problem ?

Comment: Have you looked at `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`?

Answer (score 0):

use this method . pass your urlString from this method.

```
+ (NSString *)urlEncodeValue:(NSString *)str
{
    if (str == nil) {
        return @"";
    }
    NSString *result = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)str, NULL, CFSTR("!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]%"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function for that.you have to `create dictionary` with `Parameters and value.` Hope it will help you.

```
-(id)initWith_withURL:(NSString *)strURL withParam:(NSDictionary *)dictParameter withType:(NSString *)type
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [postRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
    [postRequest setHTTPMethod:type];//set your type = GET or POST
    [postRequest setTimeoutInterval:kTimeOutInterval];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    NSMutableData  *body = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    [postRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    for (NSString *theKey in [dictParameter allKeys])
    {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n",theKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n",[dictParameter objectForKey:theKey]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    [postRequest setHTTPBody:body];
    NSLog(@"URL: %@ \nand PostData:%@",strURL,dictParameter);
    self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:postRequest delegate:self];
}
```